# What do "Refresh Data Models" and "Update Default Mappings" exactly mean?

Tags: xcode, core-data

When a **.xcmappingmodel** file is open, The **Editor** show two options:

[image]

According to my understanding, after I change the destination data model, I need to use **Update Default Mappings** to refresh the mapping model to satisfy the changed destination data model.

Am I right? And what does **Refresh Data Models** mean?